# Acceder a funciones de módulos dentro de un paquete usando diretamente el nombre del paquete

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Estoy haciendo mi propio paquete en Python, para poder importarlo desde cualquier sitio del ordenador.

La cosa es que lo he empaquetado con Python y lo he instalado con `pip`, todo bien. Ahora, lo que quiero saber es cómo hago para importar las funciones de un archivo sin tener que poner el nombre del archivo y la función, de manera que se pone el mismo nombre dos veces.

Me explico, ésta es la jerarquía de mi paquete:

> ```
> Nombre_paquete
> |
> |---archivo.py    --> Aquí se encuentra la función 1
> |
> |---archivo2.py   --> Aquí se encuentra la función 2
> ```

Ahora cuando quiero usar la función 1, tengo que escribir

```
from Nombre_paquete import archivo
archivo.funcion()
```

y a veces se repite el nombre, de manera que para usar la función tengo que escribir `test.test()`.

Lo que quiero conseguir es importar el módulo y usar las funciones como lo hace por ejemplo la librería `math`, la cual, por ejemplo, al importar la función de raíz cuadrada `sqrt()` solo tiene que poner `from math import sqrt` y directamente usa `sqrt()` sin problemas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sin modificar tu paquete lo único que puedes hacer (paquete de espacio de nombres) es importar así:

```
>>> from Nombre_paquete.archivo import funcion
>>> funcion()
```

Ahora, puedes modificar tu paquete de una forma muy simple para que sea un paquete tradicional con `__init__.py` y usarlo para inicializar el paquete, importando en su namespace todas las funciones, constantes, clases, etc que quieras hacer públicas a través del mismo de cada módulo o subpaquete:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**`__init__.py`**

```
from .modulo1 import foo
from .modulo2 import bar, PI
```

**`modulo1.py`**

```
PI = 3.14

def foo():
    print("Soy foo")
```

**`modulo2.py`**

```
def bar():
    print("Soy bar")
```

> ```
> >>> import paquete
> >>> paquete.PI
> 3.14
> >>> paquete.bar()
> Soy bar
>
> >>> from paquete import foo
> >>> foo()
> Soy foo
> ```

Si quieres exponer todo el espacio de nombres de un módulo, puedes usar wildcard:

```
from .modulo1 import *
```

pero debes ser plenamente consciente de lo que ésto implica, se añadirá al espacio de nombres del paquete todo nombre global definido en el módulo, lo que incluye lo que el propio módulo ha importado, por ejemplo:

**`modulo1.py`**

```
from math import sqrt

PI = 3.14

def foo():
    print("Soy foo")
```

**`__init__.py`**

```
from .modulo1 import *
```

> ```
> >>> import paquete
> >>> paquete.sqrt(7)   
> 2.6457513110645907
> ```

Además debes tener mucho cuidado de que los espacios de nombres de los módulos importados no se solapen entre sí (mismo nombre usado en distintos módulos) y si lo hacen que pretendas solaparlos a conciencia (que es uno de los usos legítimos de importar con wildcard).

Como comenta @abulafia puedes restringir los nombres importados por * mediante el atributo mágico `__all__`. Debe  ser una lista con los nombres que se importará del módulo cuando se use `*`.

Puedes usarlo en cualquier módulo, no solo en el `__init__.py`, dependiendo del caso, por ejemplo:

**`modulo1.py`**

```
from math import sqrt

PI = 3.14

def foo():
    print("Soy foo")

__all__ = ["foo"]
```

**`__init__.py`**

```
from .modulo1 import *
```

En este caso `from modulo1 import *` (sin importar desde dónde se haga) solo importa `foo` y por tanto solo `foo` podrá ser accedida mediante el paquete (`paquete.foo`) gracias al `__init__`.

**`modulo1.py`**

```
from math import sqrt

PI = 3.14

def foo():
    print("Soy foo")
```

**`__init__.py`**

```
from .modulo1 import *

__all__ = ["foo", "PI"]
```

En este caso `from .modulo1 import *` importa todo (`PI`y `foo`, además de `sqrt` de `math`) y podemos usarlos en el `__init__.py`, pero a través del paquete solo es accesible `foo` y `PI`.

Comment: Por completar la respuesta puedes comentar el uso de `__all__` para restringir lo que se "exporta" vía `*`

Comment: Gracias por el comentario abulafia, originalmente ni siquiera añadí la parte del start (no soy muy fan del mismo excepto para casos muy concretos, aunque este puede ser uno) , he añadido un par de ejemplos sobre el uso de la variable  `__all__`, efectivamente así está mas completa y larga para variar en mi.... XD. Un saludo.