# Importar archivos desde dentro de un paquete

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, setuptools

Quiero averiguar cómo importar una función de un archivo desde dentro del paquete. Me explico:

La jerarquía del paquete sería:

```
Carpeta
  |-Archivo 1
  |-Archivo 2
```

Dentro de cada archivo hay una función. Ahora lo que quiero hacer es importar la función del archivo 1 en el archivo 2. La cosa funciona con el `from` y con el `import`, pero una vez empaquetas e instalas el paquete, salta un error diciendo que no existe tal archivo.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Hola Esteban, ¿cómo "empaquetas"? ¿Cómo instalas? ¿Cómo tras de ejecutar o importar el paquete luego?

Comment: Creo la carpeta del paquete. lo empaqueto creando el archivo setup.py con `>>python setup.py sdist`. Una vez lo tengo listo, lo instalo con `pip`. El error viene cuando importo una de sus funciones, ya que se ve que los archivos del paquete no importan igual una vez están instalados

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vamos por partes, supongamos la siguiente estructura de archivos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**`modulo1.py`**

```
from modulo2 import foo
```

**`modulo2.py`**

```
def foo():
    print("Hola desde modulo2, soy foo :)")
```

Tal como estamos importando, solo funcionará si ejecutamos o importamos `modulo1` situados dentro de la carpeta `my_test_package`.

Si nos situamos fuera e intentamos importar a través del paquete tenemos esta bonita excepción:

> ```
> >>> from my_test_package import modulo1
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "/my_test_package/modulo1.py", line 1, in <module>
>     from modulo2 import foo
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'modulo2'
> ```

El nombre del módulo no es ya `modulo2`, es `my_test_package.module2`. Hay una explicación más detallada de ésto en ésta pregunta:

- [No puedo importar paquetes en python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/285514/15089)

Por lo tanto, el import debe cambiar a:

**`modulo1.py`**

```
from my_test_package.modulo2 import foo
```

o usando imports relativos:

**`modulo1.py`**

```
from .modulo2 import foo
```

El instalar el paquete  no hace ninguna diferencia si no hacemos cosas raras en el `setup.py`. La estructura mínima recomendada para generar nuestro paquete sería:

### Paquete de espacio de nombres (sin `__init__.py`)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**`setup.py`**

```
from setuptools import setup, find_namespace_packages


setup(
    name='my_test_package',
    version='0.1',
    description='Solo una prueba',
    url='https://mypackage.git',
    author='Author Name',
    author_email='author@email.com',
    install_requires=[],
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    packages=find_namespace_packages(where='src')
)
```

### Paquete tradicional con su `__init__.py` vacío o no

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**`setup.py`**

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages


setup(
    name='my_test_package',
    version='0.1',
    description='Solo una prueba',
    url='https://mypackage.git',
    author='Author Name',
    author_email='author@email.com',
    install_requires=[],
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    packages=find_packages(where='src')
)
```

Cualquiera de las dos versiones que usemos, generamos el paquete para distribución e instalamos:

> ```
> $ python setup.py sdist
> $ python -m pip install dist/my_test_package-0.1.tar.gz
> ```

Nos habilitará a importar nuestro módulos a través del paquete de ésta forma:

```
from my_test_package import modulo1
import my_test_package.modulo1
import my_test_package.modulo1 as mod1
from my_test_package import *
from my_test_package.modulo2 import foo
```

Hay que recordar que lo que si no podremos hacer es importar así:

> ```
> >>> import my_test_package
> >>> my_test_package.module1
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> AttributeError: module 'my_test_package' has no attribute 'module1'
> ```

Esto se debe a que importar un paquete no implica importar sus submódulos. Si queremos poder hacer esto, podemos simplemente tirar del `__init__.py` e importar los módulos que queramos exponer públicamente:

**`__init__.py`**

```
from my_test_package import modulo1, modulo2
```

con ésto y usando la segunda versión del `setup.py` al importar el paquete se importarán ambos submódulos también:

> ```
> >>> import my_test_package
> >>> my_test_package.modulo1
> <module 'my_test_package.modulo1' from '.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/my_test_package/modulo1.py'>
> >>> my_test_package.modulo2.foo()
> Hola desde modulo2, soy foo :)
> ```

- [Acceder a funciones de módulos dentro de un paquete usando diretamente el nombre del paquete](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/345392/15089)

Comment: Listo, funciona a la perfección. Espero que llegue la recompensa!