# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar un error de importación de módulos?

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones, python-import

Estoy realizando un juego de Blackjack Python pero al momento de correr el programa me sale un error de importación de las dos variables que necesito para otra función, ya intenté volviéndolas globales pero aún así el error me sigue saliendo. ¿Qué puedo hacer?

En el módulo jugadores.py tengo lo siguiente:

```
#Módulo Jugadores

def Jugadores():

  """ Esta función permite ingresar el número de jugadores y el nombre de cada uno. """

  Número_Jugadores=int(input(f"Ingrese el número de jugadores:"))

  Nombre_Jugadores=[]

  print("")

  for i in range(Número_Jugadores):

    global Nombre_Jugador
    Nombre_Jugador=input(f"Ingrese el nombre del jugador {i+1}:")

    Nombre_Jugadores.append(Nombre_Jugador)
```

En el módulo cartas.py tengo lo siguiente:

```
#Módulo Cartas

def Cartas():

  """ Esta función permite generar el mazo de cartas. """

  Valor_Cartas=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,"J","Q","K","A"]

  Palos=["Picas","Corzanones","Diamantes","Tréboles"]

  global Mazo_de_Cartas
  Mazo_de_Cartas=[]

  for Valor in Valor_Cartas:
    for Palo in Palos:
      Carta="{} de {}".format(Valor,Palo)

      Mazo_de_Cartas.append(Carta)
```

En el módulo turnos.py tengo lo siguiente:

```
#Módulo Turnos

import random
import time

from jugadores import Nombre_Jugador
from cartas import Mazo_de_Cartas

def Turno():
    Total=0
    Elección=1
    i=1

    Mazo_de_Cartas
    Cartas_Jugador=[]

    print(f"Turno de {Nombre_Jugador}:")

    while Elección!=0 and Total<21:
        Valor_Carta=0

        print (f"\nCarta #{i}:")

        time.sleep(3)

        Carta=random.choice(Mazo_de_Cartas)

        print(f"[Carta]")
```

Al correr el programa me sale lo siguiente:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
    from turnos import Turno
  File "/home/runner/Taller-03/turnos.py", line 6, in <module>
    from jugadores import Nombre_Jugador
ImportError: cannot import name 'Nombre_Jugador' from 'jugadores' (/home/runner/Taller-03/jugadores.py)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declaras la variable global `Nombre_Jugador` **dentro de la función `Jugadores`** en:

```
global Nombre_Jugador
Nombre_Jugador=input(f"Ingrese el nombre del jugador {i+1}:")
```

esto implica que **`Nombre_Jugador` no existe hasta que la función es llamada**. Cuando importas por tanto no existe, el cuerpo de una función no es evaluado cuando se importa un módulo, solo se evalúa cuando es ejecutada.

No obstante, usar variables globales es una muy mala práctica si no es para variables de estado o constantes, dificulta la legibilidad del código y lo hace propenso a bugs difíciles de depurar en muchos casos.

Además, hay que tener en cuenta que las variables globales en Python los son solo a nivel de módulo, no a nivel de proceso. Modificar por tanto la variable en el módulo principal no afecta al valor que tiene en el resto.

No necesitas hacer que esas variables sean globales, haz que las funciones retornen cosas y acepten argumentos, más legible, más escalable y más seguro. Algo como:

**`jugadores.py`**

```
import random
import time


def turno(nombre_jugador, mazo_de_cartas):
    total = 0
    elección = 1
    num_carta = 1

    cartas_jugador = []

    print(f"Turno de {nombre_jugador}: ")

    while elección != 0 and total < 21:
        valor_carta = 0
        print(f"\nCarta #{total + 1}: ")
        time.sleep(3)
        carta = random.choice(mazo_de_cartas)
        cartas_jugador.append(carta)
        total += 1
        print(f"{carta}")

    return cartas_jugador
```

**`cartas.py`**

```
VALOR_CARTAS = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,"J", "Q", "K", "A"]
PALOS = ["Picas", "Corazones", "Diamantes", "Tréboles"]

def obtener_mazo():

    """ Esta función permite generar el mazo de cartas. """

    mazo_de_cartas = []

    for valor in VALOR_CARTAS:
        for palo in PALOS:
            carta = f"{valor} de {palo}"
            mazo_de_cartas.append(carta)
    return mazo_de_cartas
```

**`turnos.py`**

```
import random
import time


def turno(nombre_jugador, mazo_de_cartas):
    total = 0
    elección = 1
    num_carta = 1

    cartas_jugador = []

    print(f"Turno de {nombre_jugador}: ")

    while elección != 0 and total < 21:
        valor_carta = 0
        print(f"\nCarta #{total + 1}: ")
        time.sleep(3)
        carta = random.choice(mazo_de_cartas)
        cartas_jugador.append(carta)
        total += 1
        print(f"{carta}")

    return cartas_jugador
```

`main.py`

```
from jugadores import obtener_jugadores
from cartas import obtener_mazo
from turnos import turno


jugadores = obtener_jugadores()
mazo = obtener_mazo()

for jugador in jugadores:
    cartas_jugador = turno(jugador, mazo)
    print(f"Jugador: {jugador}, cartas elegidas: {cartas_jugador}")
```

Te recomiendo así mismo seguir las convenciones de estilo definidas en:

- [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

---

- Los nombres de módulos, funciones, métodos y variables deben ser en minúsculas y usando `_` como separador. El `CamelCase` se reserva para nombrar clases y `NOMBRE_CONSTANTE` para constantes.
- A ser posible usa siempre cuatro espacios por nivel de identación.

Para más información sobre errores de importación de módulos/paquetes ver:

- [No puedo importar paquetes en python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/285514/no-puedo-importar-paquetes-en-python)

Comment: Muchas gracias por los consejos!

Comment: respondiste una respuesta hace un tiempo de como importar modulos, deberia agregarla para complementarla

Comment: mire [maestro!!](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/347608/importar-archivos-desde-dentro-de-un-paquete/348560#348560)

Comment: Hola @JackNavaRow, gracias por la recomendación, he añadido un enlace a la pregunta. Justo andaba editando la pregunta, reetiquetando de acuerdo a [¿Deberían las etiquetas \[import\] e \[importación\] ser sinónimas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4700/deber%c3%adan-las-etiquetas-import-e-importaci%c3%b3n-ser-sin%c3%b3nimas) para que fedorqui no termine haciéndolo todo él como tantas veces XD...